# Python extended slicing confused

Tags: python

So I understand that Python has extended slicing which will grab substring with [start:end:step], with default values for start and end.

So for example:

```
L = range(6)
>>>L[::2]
[0, 2, 4, 6]
```

Okay makes sense... no value for start so it defaults to 0, then increments by 2.

```
>>>L[::-1]
[6, 4, 2, 0]
```

Now this is where i'm really confused. No value for start so it should be 0, but it starts at back of list... ??  Shouldn't it be [0, 6, 4, 2]? Why does step = -1 give special behavior for starting at back of list?

Comment: Your result in the second example is incorrect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is documented along with everything else [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) (emphasis added):

> `s[i:j:k]`
>
> If i or j are omitted or None, they become “end” values (**which end depends on the sign of k**).